# Find nearest index in one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance, nearest-neighbor

I am new to python and its libraries. Searched all the forums but could not find a proper solution. This is the first time posting a question here. Sorry if I did something wrong.

So, I have two DataFrames like below containing X Y Z coordinates (UTM) and other features.

```py
In [2]: a = {
   ...:     'X': [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 5, 2, 3, 24, 21],
   ...:     'Y': [3, 4, 8, 15, 20, 12, 23, 22, 14, 7],
   ...:     'Z': [12, 4, 9, 16, 13, 1, 8, 17, 11, 19],
   ...: }
   ...:
In [3]: b = {
   ...:     'X': [1, 8, 20, 7, 32],
   ...:     'Y': [6, 4, 17, 45, 32],
   ...:     'Z': [52, 12, 6, 8, 31],
   ...: }

In [4]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
In [5]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
In [6]: print(df1)
    X   Y   Z
0   1   3  12
1   2   4   4
2   5   8   9
3   7  15  16
4  10  20  13
5   5  12   1
6   2  23   8
7   3  22  17
8  24  14  11
9  21   7  19

In [7]: print(df2)
    X   Y   Z
0   1   6  52
1   8   4  12
2  20  17   6
3   7  45   8
4  32  32  31
```

I need to find the closest point (distance) in df1 to each point of df2 and creating new DataFrame.

So I wrote the code below and actually find the closest point (distance) to df2.iloc[0].

```
In [8]: x = (
   ...:     np.sqrt(
   ...:         ((df1['X'].sub(df2["X"].iloc[0]))**2)
   ...:         .add(((df1['Y'].sub(df2["Y"].iloc[0]))**2))
   ...:         .add(((df1['Z'].sub(df2["Z"].iloc[0]))**2))
   ...:     )
   ...: ).idxmin()

In [9]: x1 = df1.iloc[[x]]
In[10]: print(x1)
   X   Y   Z
3  7  15  16
```

So, I guess I need a loop to iterate through df2 and apply above code to each row. As a result I need a new updated df1 containing all the closest points to each point of df2. But couldn't make it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a great example of a case where numpy's broadcasting rules have distinct advantages over pandas.

Manually aligning df1's coordinates as column vectors (by referencing `df1[[col]].to_numpy()`) and df2's coordinates as row vectors (`df2[col].to_numpy()`), we can get the distance from every element in each dataframe to each element in the other very quickly with automatic broadcasting:

```py
In [26]: dists = np.sqrt(
    ...:     (df1[['X']].to_numpy() - df2['X'].to_numpy()) ** 2
    ...:     + (df1[['Y']].to_numpy() - df2['Y'].to_numpy()) ** 2
    ...:     + (df1[['Z']].to_numpy() - df2['Z'].to_numpy()) ** 2
    ...: )

In [27]: dists
Out[27]:
array([[40.11234224,  7.07106781, 24.35159132, 42.61455151, 46.50806382],
       [48.05205511, 10.        , 22.29349681, 41.49698784, 49.12229636],
       [43.23193264,  5.83095189, 17.74823935, 37.06750599, 42.29657197],
       [37.58989226, 11.74734012, 16.52271164, 31.04834939, 33.74907406],
       [42.40283009, 16.15549442, 12.56980509, 25.67099531, 30.85449724],
       [51.50728104, 13.92838828, 16.58312395, 33.7934905 , 45.04442252],
       [47.18050445, 20.32240143, 19.07878403, 22.56102835, 38.85871846],
       [38.53569774, 19.33907961, 20.85665361, 25.01999201, 33.7194306 ],
       [47.68647607, 18.89444363,  7.07106781, 35.48239   , 28.0713377 ],
       [38.60051813, 15.06651917, 16.43167673, 41.96427052, 29.83286778]])
```

Argmin will now give you the correct vector of positional indices:

```py
In [28]: dists.argmin(axis=0)
Out[28]: array([3, 2, 8, 6, 8])
```

Or, to select the appropriate values from df1:

```py
In [29]: df1.iloc[dists.argmin(axis=0)]
Out[29]:
    X   Y   Z
3   7  15  16
2   5   8   9
8  24  14  11
6   2  23   8
8  24  14  11
```

## Edit

An answer popped up just after mine, then was deleted, which made reference to [`scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html), computing `dists` with:

```py
distance_matrix(df1[list('XYZ')].to_numpy(), df2[list('XYZ')].to_numpy())
```

Not sure why that answer was deleted, but this seems like a really nice, clean approach to getting the array I produced manually above!

## Performance Note

Note that if you are just trying to get the closest value, there's no need to take the square root, as this is a costly operation compared to addition, subtraction, and powers, and sorting on `dist**2` is still valid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Both approaches solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you define a function that returns the closest point using numpy.where. Then you use the apply function to run through df2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {
   'X': [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 5, 2, 3, 24, 21],
   'Y': [3, 4, 8, 15, 20, 12, 23, 22, 14, 7],
   'Z': [12, 4, 9, 16, 13, 1, 8, 17, 11, 19]
 }
b = {
   'X': [1, 8, 20, 7, 32],
   'Y': [6, 4, 17, 45, 32],
   'Z': [52, 12, 6, 8, 31]
 }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

dist = lambda dx,dy,dz: np.sqrt(dx**2+dy**2+dz**2)

def closest(row):
    darr = dist(df1['X']-row['X'], df1['Y']-row['Y'], df1['Z']-row['Z'])
    idx = np.where(darr == np.amin(darr))[0][0]
    return df1['X'][idx], df1['Y'][idx], df1['Z'][idx]

df2['closest'] = df2.apply(closest, axis=1)

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    X   Y   Z       closest
0   1   6  52   (7, 15, 16)
1   8   4  12     (5, 8, 9)
2  20  17   6  (24, 14, 11)
3   7  45   8    (2, 23, 8)
4  32  32  31  (24, 14, 11)
```